# Extra space not wanted at the end of a title page

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I did a title page using the titlepage environment and used \vfill between the entries (for instance name, title, date, etc.) so that they would be equally spaced and the whole title page would fill all of the page.

This implies that there should be an equal blank space at the top of the page (before my first entry) and at the bottom of the page (after my last entry). Nevertheless, it is not what I get. What can I do to fix it? I do not want to alter my geometry settings.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[c]{--~\thepage~--}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in}
\begin{titlepage} 
\begin{center}
\textbf{Name of the lab} \par
Blabla
\vfill
Title
\vfill
\normalsize\textbf{Name}
\vfill
Report presented to: \par
Someone
\vfill
\today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Blank space before the first entry:
[image]
Blank space after the last entry:
[image]

Comment: If you add `showframe` in the options to `geometry`, you'll see what LaTeX thinks about the various page elements. There is an additional space below the date because you have the `center` environment; use `\centering` just after `\begin{titlepage}` and remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two factors that influence your problem. The default behavior of `geometry` is to divide the available vertical space for the top and bottom margins in a ratio 2:3. Another slight source for space is the usage of the `center` environment. Just use `\centering` that doesn't add vertical space.

You can look at how `geometry` sets the page elements by adding the `showframe` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in,showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[c]{--~\thepage~--}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in,vmarginratio=1:1}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\textbf{Name of the lab} \par
Blabla
\vfill
Title
\vfill
\normalsize\textbf{Name}
\vfill
Report presented to: \par
Someone
\vfill
\today
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\section*{Introduction}
\vfill
\begin{center}
1
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]